# How to handle window unload function?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery the window unload function is not working properly.

Suppose I have to go to another page like Google. It asks "are you sure you want to leave the page?". When I click "Leave" it doesn't work? Any solution please?

My code is here, please run it in Chrome. Suppose the page where I have to go is Google.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var c = confirm("Are you sure  to leave?");
    if(c) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/86fa4ry3/. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You can't put  `confirm` in `'beforeunload'`, it will never fire

Comment: than any solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, but you can't call some functions in this event. `confirm` is one.

MDN says:

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more
>   details.

See more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: i get it but to go to some other page is creating problem for me .. when i click on leave it doesnt load to that page .